# Facebook Login and django-social-auth how to debug

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, python-social-auth

I'm using (python-social-auth)[http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/facebook.html#oauth2] to login to Facebook, the thing is that suddenly it stop working. The error that I'm getting is `Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later.`.
I updated the code of python-social-auth to ```social-auth-core==1.4.0``, so I know I'm using facebook's 2.9 version.
Is there another way to debug what's going on?

Comment: This was a temporary bug, should be fixed by now.

Comment: Yuhuuu!! yep! thanks a lot!